# Listfragment crashes when tab selected and gives errors

Tags: android, android-listfragment

When i run my app everything runs perfectly until i select the third tab that consist the listfragment i made so it displays a listview with data and image, once it is selected the app just gives the normal message unfortunately the app stopped working and logcat sends a lot of red errors.

```
03-06 01:44:23.200: D/dalvikvm(879): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 6% free 3113K/3280K, paused 57ms, total 59ms
03-06 01:44:23.410: D/dalvikvm(879): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 5% free 3143K/3280K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
03-06 01:44:23.410: I/dalvikvm-heap(879): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.811MB for 709972-byte allocation
03-06 01:44:23.450: D/dalvikvm(879): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 3836K/3976K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
03-06 01:44:23.530: D/(879): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7a51a38, tid 879
03-06 01:44:23.690: W/EGL_emulation(879): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 01:44:23.700: D/OpenGLRenderer(879): Enabling debug mode 0
03-06 01:44:35.760: D/AndroidRuntime(879): Shutting down VM
03-06 01:44:35.760: W/dalvikvm(879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aa8ba8)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Process: com.TIPA.uips, PID: 879
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.TIPA.uips.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:71)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1105)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-06 01:44:35.810: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 01:44:39.230: I/Process(879): Sending signal. PID: 879 SIG: 9
```

The main thing that i changed in this class was it use to be `extends Fragment` to `extends ListFragment` i believe this is creating the error although not sure how?

```
package com.TIPA.uips;

import com.TIPA.uips.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FriendsList extends ListFragment {

     public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

      Context myContext;

      public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] objects) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
       myContext = context;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

       LayoutInflater inflater = 
         (LayoutInflater)myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
       TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.carrottop);
       label.setText(month[position]);
       ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.dp);

       //Customize your icon here
       icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dp);

       return row;
      }

     }

     String[] month ={
       "^Smithy", 
       "^Kreso", 
       "^Chen", 
       "^Dave"
     };

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      /*
      ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        month);
      setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
      */
      MyListAdapter myListAdapter = 
        new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, month);
      setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list, container, false);
     }

     @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(
        getActivity(), 
        getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

    }
```

This here is the adapter to allow the fragments to return the values of each class believing it is not allowing it.

```
package com.TIPA.uips;

import com.TIPA.uips.NewsFeed;
import com.TIPA.uips.Chat;
import com.TIPA.uips.FriendsList;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new NewsFeed();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new Chat();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FriendsList();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Cheers

UPDATE:

New error occuring when implemented listview in xml with id/list.

```
03-06 02:47:59.780: D/dalvikvm(858): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-06 02:48:02.290: D/dalvikvm(858): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 95K, 6% free 3117K/3284K, paused 52ms, total 54ms
03-06 02:48:02.510: D/dalvikvm(858): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 19K, 5% free 3143K/3284K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
03-06 02:48:02.510: I/dalvikvm-heap(858): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.815MB for 709972-byte allocation
03-06 02:48:02.550: D/dalvikvm(858): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 3836K/3980K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
03-06 02:48:02.640: D/(858): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb74f2a38, tid 858
03-06 02:48:02.750: W/EGL_emulation(858): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 02:48:02.760: D/OpenGLRenderer(858): Enabling debug mode 0
03-06 02:48:07.920: D/AndroidRuntime(858): Shutting down VM
03-06 02:48:07.920: W/dalvikvm(858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a74ba8)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858): Process: com.TIPA.uips, PID: 858
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.TIPA.uips.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:71)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1105)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-06 02:48:07.940: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 02:48:09.880: I/Process(858): Sending signal. PID: 858 SIG: 9
```

Friends_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Problem is in your xml..u need to give id of list view as @android:id/list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a listview with id as below in  `friends_list.xml`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Whatever applies to `ListActivity` applies to `ListFragment`. More info @

Quoting docs

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

So if you inflate a layout in `ListFragment` you need to have a `ListView` with the id `@android:id/list` in the fragments layout.

Edit:

Notice  `android:id="@+id/list"` vs `android:id="@android:id/list"`. I suggested `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Hi thankyou for the response i have done exaclty that and now im getting an error also when selecting the second tab, the listview added into my xml is id/list. Here is the error. I placed the error in the main thread

Comment: @vyrix09 what is the 344 is ListFragment?

Comment: @vyrix09 and post `friends_list.xml`.

Comment: i posted the friends_list.xml now, thankyou for the help.
The 344 says its  a ListFragment, in the error beside it hopefully im right.

Comment: @vyrix09 use `android:id="@android:id/list"` instead of this `android:id="@+id/list"`. Re- Read my post carefully

Comment: All i can say is from the bottom of my heart to the highest heavens i give you my gratitude and great knowledge that is bestowed upon me. It worked :)