# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, listview, android-logcat

I am writing an app in which i am using ListView, but whenever i do run my program getting :-

**Log says:-**

```
03-07 12:24:34.030: E/AndroidRuntime(20663): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

**onCreate() method :-**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217171/listfragment-crashes-when-tab-selected-and-gives-errors/22217236#22217236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the id to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Like this:

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```